# how does IPython magics work

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

ipthon-sql is an extension of ipython, I first install it by pip install ipython-sql

the project is here: https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql

and my problem is:

when I enter %load_ext sql and press SHIFT+ENTER, what's the detailed procedure of IPython to execute this magic sentence? thanks ...

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run any code in the notebook, an `execute_request` is sent via the notebook server, to a 'kernel', a process which executes your code.

When the kernel receives your code, it runs it through a sequence of input transformers. One of these detects that this line is a magic command, and rewrites it to:

```
get_ipython().magic('load_ext sql')
```

You can see these translated commands using `%hist -t`.

The `.magic()` method takes the first word of its argument, `load_ext`, and looks it up in a dictionary. You can see that dictionary by running:

```
get_ipython().magics_manager.magics['line']
```

(this may be a bit different depending on your version of IPython)

That gives it a reference to the method `IPython.core.magics.extension.ExtensionMagics.load_ext`, which you can see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/rel-3.0.0/IPython/core/magics/extension.py#L59). It calls that method with the remainder of the string.

That method imports the package `sql`, and calls `sql.load_ipython_extension(ip)` to set it up. It's up to the extension what it does then - in this case, it registers some new magic functions.