# Using magic command %% timeit -n1 -r1 causes jupyter does not keep the value of local variables

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I just noticed to something very strange. When I use `%%timeit -n1 -r1` magic command, to measure the execution time of a block of code in Jupyter lab, python does not keep the value of local variables after the execution of the block!
For instance, if I run a block of code containing the following codes:

```
for i in range(10):
   for j in range(10):
       d = i - j
```

and then run `print(d)` in another block, the jupyter will show me the value of d in the last iteration. 
But if I run this block of code:

```
%%timeit -n1 -r1
for in in range(10):
   for j in range(10):
       d = i - j
```

and then run `print(d)`, the juoyter shows me an error message:

```
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

What is the explanation behind this strange behaviour?

Comment: `for in in range(10):` should that not be `for i in range(10):`?

Comment: @Hoog, sorry, it was a typo! I just corrected it

Comment: I was in need of not just the explanation but also on how to get around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

IPython/Jupyter takes the block of code in the cell and runs it in a function whose scope is not visible to your `__main__` module's namespace.  Judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29262880/7954504), it seems to take the cell as a string:

```
In [4]: get_ipython().magic('timeit 1 + 2')                                                                                                                                                                        
11.2 ns ± 0.167 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

In [5]: %%timeit 
   ...: 1 + 2 
   ...:  
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
11.1 ns ± 0.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

The variables from the loop are known to whatever IPython function runs and times the loop, but not accessible outside of that `Timer` instance method.

When you run the `for i in range(10)` loop (without `%%timeit`) in a cell (or just in a plain-vanilla Python interactive interpreter), the way that Python handles a for-loop is to dynamically re-assign the `i`, `j`, and `d` values in each iteration of the loop.  They will still be sitting around in the namespace of `__main__` (this is the `__name__` dunder attribute in a Python shell) after the loop has run its course.